# alter authorization on schema::xxx to [Domain\user1] cannot grant the permission for schema?

Tags: sql-server

The following SQL got the permission denied error.

```
drop schema xxx; -- run if xxx exists
go
create schema xxx;
go
alter authorization on schema::xxxto [Domain\user1]
exec ('create view xxx.x as select 1 a') as login = 'Domain\user1'
go
```

> CREATE VIEW permission denied in database '....'

And the following error got the same error too.

```
drop schema xxx;
go
create schema xxx;
go
GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::[xxx] TO [Domain\user1]
exec ('create view xxx.x as select 1 a') as login = 'Domain\user1'
go
```

Why it's not working?

Comment: Database user member of dbcreator server role?

Comment: Below SQL works fine for me: DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS XXX;
GO

CREATE SCHEMA XXX;
GO

GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::[xxx] TO [Servername\TestUser]
EXEC ('create view xxx.A as select 1 a') as login = 'Servername\TestUser'
GO